# Can someone help analyze the structure of the second clause?

Tags: sentence-structure, participle-clauses

Below is the example:

> Wind will power the tower’s motion, making it the first self-powered skyscraper in history.

Since participial clauses share the same subject. Is "wind" the subject for the verb of make in the second clause?

Answer (score 4):

Participial clauses do not always share subjects with other clauses. (If anyone told you that they do, then that person was very mistaken.) In this case, it makes no sense for "wind" to be "making it the first self-powered skyscraper in history." It is clearly the fact that wind will power the tower’s motion that makes it the first self-powered skyscraper in history. Therefore, the entire main clause ("wind will power the tower’s motion") serves as the subject (or agent) of the verb "making".

Comment: Hi MarcIn, Thanks for your explanation. I still have confused why is the verb "make" formed with" ing " not simply as "make it the first self-powered skyscraper in history"

Comment: "Make" could be the base infinitive form or a finite form. However, there is no reason for either. "Making" could be the present participle form, and that does make sense, because present participles are sometimes used to modify clauses. (I'm not being very precise with terms because people tend to use a variety of terminology for this structure. The main point is that the precent participle form can be justified based on syntax while those other forms can't. The full infinitive form "to make" could also work.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes wind is the subject. "Making," without a subject being mentioned in thee second clausez, you cab imply that it has the same subject as the first clause.

You will see many sentences like this; it is very complete consisting of a
independent and dependent clause.

Comment: But, as Marcin has said, that makes no sense. "Wind" has no part in making it _the first_ anything.

Comment: Note also that a subject **is** mentioned. Ask yourself, What makes it the first self-powered skyscraper? The answer is the whole first clause: "Wind powering the motion of the tower." So that clause as a whole functions as the subject. (as Marcin has explained well.)